# Sending contents of a php file (dynamically loaded using Jquery load method) using PHPMailer

Tags: php, jquery, phpmailer

This is my first question on this community. However I have been using it from a long time for any technical difficulties and It's been a great help.

Anyway my question is:

I am loading content in a div of mail_contents.php from another PHP file shopping_cart.php using:

```
$("#mail_contents").load('shopping_cart.php #cart_contents');
```

When I directly open the mail_contents.php in my browser I can see the content too.

But the issue is when I am trying to send the content of this php file in email using the below code:

```
.....
$mailer = new PHPMailer();
$mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';
$mailer->IsHTML(true); 

$mailer->AddAddress($this->UserEmail());

$mailer->Subject = "You have placed an order with ".$this->sitename;

$mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();

$mailer->FromName = "POR";   

ob_start();
include 'mail_contents.php';

$content = ob_get_clean();

$mailer->Body = $content;

if(!$mailer->Send()){
$this->HandleError("Failed sending user welcome email.");
return false;
}
return true;
....
```

I am not able to see the content, loaded dynamically. I added some static code in my mail_contents.php file using echo statement and I found that it is appearing successfully in my email. Please guide me if I am doing something wrong.

Thanks is Advance!!

Comment: Do I need to provide some other information?

Answer (score 0):

try this one out:

```
ob_start();
   include 'mail_contents.php';
$content = ob_get_clean();

$mail->MsgHTML($content, dirname(__FILE__));
```

And tell me, if this is working or not.